# How to specify API Gateway URL in cloudformation script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am using cloudformation script yaml file to create resources on AWS dev account.

My goal is to create a lambda function with API gateway endpoint. The lambda function is created successfully and also the gateway within it. But when I tried to specify the API end point URL in the script, I am greeted with the following error.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid API identifier specified 442645024664:test-api- 
gateway-ms (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 404, Request ID: 47e0c115-02c4-4dfd-b13a- 
b149c72807cf)" (RequestToken: a3fdecd7-41fd-cfef-f538-2da3bac33ec2, HandlerErrorCode: 
NotFound)
```

Below is my stack from template.yaml.

```
Parameters:
  MyApi:
  Type: String
  Description: "This is a demo API"
  AllowedValues: [ "dev-demo-lambda-api-poc" ]

Resources:
  MyDemoLambdaApiFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
    Currently does not support S3 upload event.
  Handler: app.lambda_handler
  Runtime: python3.11
  CodeUri: .
  MemorySize: 1028
  Events:
    MyDemoAPI:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /test
        Method: GET
  Tracing: Active

Deployment:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  Properties:
    Description: Demo Lambda API Gateway deployment
    RestApiId: !Ref MyApi

Outputs:
  MyApiUrl:
  Description: API Gateway URL
  Value:
    Fn::Sub: https://dev-demo-lambda-api-poc
```

Setting aside the error, Iam bit confused here when creating the endpoint for the API. What's the correct way of providing the end point URL in the CFN script?

I believe I should first Deploy this before I can have the end point?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `correct way of providing the end point URL in the CFN script`? Do you want to provide your own URL? Or you want to get (Output) the URL of you APIGW?

Comment: Both of course. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Outputs**

To output the default API Gateway endpoint you need to follow this format:

`https://{api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}`

```
Outputs:
  MyApiDefaultUrl:
    Description: API Gateway URL
    Value: !Sub "https://${MyApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/<stageName>"

# Where:
# ${MyApiGateway} is the reference to you API Gateway resource
# <stageName> is the Stage Name

# If you have a separate AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
Outputs:
  MyApiDefaultUrl:
  Description: My API Gateway Default URL
  Value: !Sub "https://${MyApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${MyApiStage}"
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

---

**Custom Domain Name**

To give your API a custom domain name, you need to use `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName`.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html for the template.

See [Setting up custom domain names for REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) for the prerequisites.